# Pisano Period - Fibonacci

Tags: algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

I have to construct an algorithm which will return a fibonacci number mod another integer. I know that i have to implement the Pisano period. I know how to receive it, but the problem comes when I obtain the number $$F_n \ Mod\ Period$$
How to proceed the computation?

Comment: what language are you going to use?

Comment: I am going to use c++

Comment: In C and C++, $x = a ~\% ~b$ means "$x$ is the the result of $a$ mod $b$".